# C# String Formatting Different in Console Compared to Text File

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Can anyone tell me why the following screenshots are different even though they are the same string?

The first is the output from Console.WriteLine(myString) and the second is from the exact same string written to a text file.

[Console.WriteLine(myString)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pu0Z.png)

[String when output to text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwHtP.png)

Tried multiple formatting approaches and always the same result.

Comment: What does the string contain? The only difference seems to be the font - terminals use fixed width fonts, all other applications use variable width fonts. Including this page. [*a*] is wider than [*i*]

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't have precise layout in a text file. Locations will always depend on the font used by the editor. To get precise formatting you'd have to generate an HTML or Excel file. PDF is an option too, but it's harder

Comment: Check the [Monospaced Fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) page in Wikipedia which explains the difference between the monospaced fonts used in terminals and code editors and proportional, which are used by all other applications, including document editors and viewers

Comment: Because console and text editor use different fonts to show the same text.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all. Looks like I'll have to generate a CSV or XLSX instead of the text file if I want to keep the "table" formatted output.